# How to convert a html table with cells that span into several columns into a list of lists in Python 3?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I am new to Python and have started a little project that needs some webscraping. I started using BS4 but I am getting a little stuck while trying to convert a html table with cells that span into several columns into a list of lists (in Python 3).

I want to convert this html table into a list of lists, in order to be able to print it in text-mode with terminaltables. So, I was trying to get some empty list cells to fill the rest of the row wherever there is an HTML cell that spans for 5 columns.

I think I am probably overcomplicating something that could be done a lot easier in (fluent) Python. Can anyone help?

My code at this time:

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/python3
    # encoding: utf-8
    


    # just did a lot of experiments, so I will need to clean these imports! (some of them are related to the rest of the project anyway)
import sys
    import os
    import os.path
    import csv
    import re
    from textwrap import fill as tw_fill
    from random import randint
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from copy import deepcopy
    from platform import node
    

    from colorclass import Color
    from urllib3 import PoolManager
    from bleach import clean
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from terminaltables import SingleTable
    
        
    
    def obter_estado_detalhado(tracking_code):
        """ Verify detailed tracking status for CTT shipment
        Ex: obter_estado_detalhado("EA746000000PT")
        """    
        ctt_url = "http://www.cttexpresso.pt/feapl_2/app/open/cttexpresso/objectSearch/objectSearch.jspx?lang=def&objects=" + tracking_code + "&showResults=true"
        estado = "- N/A -"
        
        dados_tracking = [[
            "Hora",
            "Estado",
            "Motivo",
            "Local",
            "Recetor"
            ]
        ]
        
    #    try:
        http = PoolManager()
        r = http.urlopen('GET', ctt_url, preload_content=False)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
        records = dados_tracking
        table2 = soup.find_all('table')[1]
    
        l = 1
        c = 0
        for linha in table2.find_all('tr')[1:]:
            records.append([])
            for celula in linha.find_all('td')[1:]:
                txt = clean(celula.string, tags=[], strip=True).strip()
                records[l].append(txt)
                c += 1
            l += 1
            tabela = SingleTable(records)
            print(tabela.table)
        
        print(records)
        tabela = SingleTable(records)
        print(tabela.table)
        exit()  # This exit is only for testing purposes...
        
    
    
    obter_estado_detalhado("EA746813946PT")
```

Sample HTML code [(as in this link)](http://www.cttexpresso.pt/feapl_2/app/open/cttexpresso/objectSearch/objectSearch.jspx?lang=def&objects=EA746813946PT&showResults=true):

```
<table class="full-width">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Nº de Objeto 
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Produto
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Data
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Hora
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Estado
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Info
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td>
                            
                                EA746813813PT                                   
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                        </td>    
                        <td>19</td> 
                        <td>2016/03/31</td> 
                        <td>09:40</td>

                        <td>
                                                                    
                                
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                        Objeto entregue
                                    
                                
                                                        
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="truncate">
                            <a id="detailsLinkShow_0" onclick="toggleObjectDetails('0', true);" class="hide">[+]Info</a>
                            <a id="detailsLinkHide_0" class="" onclick="toggleObjectDetails('0', false);">[-]Info</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr id="details_0" class="">
                        <td colspan="6">
                        
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                                        
                        
                            
                            <div class="full-width-table-scroller"><table class="full-width">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Hora</th>
                                        <th>Estado</th>
                                        <th>Motivo</th>
                                        
                                        <th>Recetor</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                
                                            </tr>
                                        
                                        <tr class="group">                          
                                                <td colspan="5">quinta-feira, 31 Março 2016</td>
                                            </tr><tr><td>09:40</td>  
                                        <td>Entrega conseguida</td> 
                                        <th>Local</th><td>-</td> 
                                        <td>4470 - MAIA</td>
                                        <td>DONIEL MARQUES</td> 
                                    </tr>   
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        
                                        <td>08:32</td>   
                                        <td>Em distribuição</td> 
                                        <td>-</td> 
                                        <td>4470 - MAIA</td>
                                        <td>-</td>  
                                    </tr>   
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        
                                        <td>08:29</td>   
                                        <td>Receção no local de entrega</td> 
                                        <td>-</td> 
                                        <td>4470 - MAIA</td>
                                        <td>-</td>  
                                    </tr>   
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        
                                        <td>08:29</td>   
                                        <td>Receção nacional</td> 
                                        <td>-</td> 
                                        <td>4470 - MAIA</td>
                                        <td>-</td>  
                                    </tr>   
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        
                                        <td>00:17</td>   
                                        <td>Envio</td> 
                                        <td>-</td> 
                                        <td>C. O. PERAFITA</td>
                                        <td>-</td>  
                                    </tr>   
                                
                                    <tr>
                                                
                                            </tr><tr class="group">                         
                                                <td colspan="5">quarta-feira, 30 Março 2016</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        
                                        <tr><td>23:40</td>   
                                        <td>Expedição nacional</td> 
                                        <td>-</td> 
                                        <td>C.O. PERAFITA (OPE)</td>
                                        <td>-</td>  
                                    </tr>   
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        
                                        <td>20:39</td>   
                                        <td>Receção no local de entrega</td> 
                                        <td>-</td> 
                                        <td>C. O. PERAFITA</td>
                                        <td>-</td>  
                                    </tr>   
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        
                                        <td>20:39</td>   
                                        <td>Receção nacional</td> 
                                        <td>-</td> 
                                        <td>C. O. PERAFITA</td>
                                        <td>-</td>  
                                    </tr>   
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        
                                        <td>20:39</td>   
                                        <td>Aceitação</td> 
                                        <td>-</td> 
                                        <td>C. O. PERAFITA</td>
                                        <td>-</td>  
                                    </tr>   
                                    
                            </tbody></table></div>
                                
                            
                            
                            
                            
                        </td>
                </tr>       
        
        </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Obviously, I intend to add a try/except in order to catch any connection problems, but right now I am trying to get the html parsing right.

Comment: Can you link to the url as trying to look through the posted html is a bit painful

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Here it is: [link](http://www.cttexpresso.pt/feapl_2/app/open/cttexpresso/objectSearch/objectSearch.jspx?lang=def&objects=EA746813946PT&showResults=true)

Comment: @Viktor, I added an answer that replicates what you see on the page. If you want the headers above that also it is easy to add but I am not sure if it is relevant or not  as I don't speak what looks like portuguese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches the main table output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("http://www.cttexpresso.pt/feapl_2/app/open/cttexpresso/objectSearch/objectSearch.jspx?lang=def&objects=EA746813946PT&showResults=true").content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# get table using id
rows = soup.select("#details_0")[0]

# get the header names and strip whitespace
cols = [th.text.strip() for th in rows.select("th")]

# extract all td's from each table row, the list comp will data grouped row wise.
data = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.select("td")] for tr in rows.select("tr")]

print(" ".join(cols))
for row in data:
    print(", ".join(row))
```

Output:

```
Hora Estado Motivo Local Recetor


terça-feira, 5 Abril 2016
07:58, Em distribuição, -, 4000 - PORTO, -
00:35, Envio, -, C. O. PERAFITA, -
00:20, Expedição nacional, -, C.O. PERAFITA (OPE), -

segunda-feira, 4 Abril 2016
21:45, Receção nacional, -, C. O. PERAFITA, -
21:45, Aceitação, -, C. O. PERAFITA, -
```

Website:

[image]

It was the parser, I thought I tried them all nut the only one that worked was *html5* using `soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5")`  outputted:

```
Hora Estado Motivo Local Recetor


terça-feira, 5 Abril 2016
11:02, Entrega conseguida, -, 4000 - PORTO, CANDIDA VIEGAS
07:58, Em distribuição, -, 4000 - PORTO, -
00:35, Envio, -, C. O. PERAFITA, -
00:20, Expedição nacional, -, C.O. PERAFITA (OPE), -

segunda-feira, 4 Abril 2016
21:45, Receção no local de entrega, -, C. O. PERAFITA, -
21:45, Receção nacional, -, C. O. PERAFITA, -
21:45, Aceitação, -, C. O. PERAFITA, -
```

Comment: Nice! :) I just added a line of code to merge the header on top of the data list: 'data.insert(0, cols)'

Comment: One entry is actually missing, `Receção no local de entrega`, not sure why as it is a sibling of the other td's,  I will figure it out in a bit

Comment: Well, here it seems to be working just fine. That entry is ok in my computer.

Comment: I still need to take a moment to read your code carefully and learn something from it. It works, but I confess I still don't understand it as I should. :-)

Comment: @Victor, it was the parser I was using, lxml and html.parse both gave weird output.  It is actually pretty straight forward, if you replace the list comps with regular loops and put a few prints in you will see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Going back to the chapter on list comprehensions :-) I have seen it before but did not experiment. I got to do that right now.